# Extending a subset of $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have a linearly independent subset of $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ and I'm trying to extend it to a basis.  I heard this can be done, but I can't find an algorithm for actually doing it.  Can you help me?

Also, what if it wasn't a subset of $\mathbb{F}_q^n$, but rather an arbitrary vector space $V$?

Thanks!

Comment: Let $v_i$ be the vector all of whose coordinates are $0$ except the $i$-th coordinate, which is $1$. Take your linearly independent subset $S_0$. Test whether $S_0\cup\{v_1\}$ is a linearly independent set or not. If linearly independent, add $v_1$ to $S_0$, to get $S_1$. If not linearly independent, discard $v_1$. Continue to $v_2$. It may save time to do the requisite row reductions simultaneously.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: is there a fast way to determine whether a set is linearly independent?

Comment: For small collections, eyeballing usually works. For larger ones, use row reduction.  The answer by Quimey says this.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Okay, thanks :)

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but what is $\Bbb F^n_q$?

Comment: @DavidMitra The set of vectors of length $n$ with elements in the field $\mathbb{F}_q$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gaussian elimination algorithm might be useful. Take a look at [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#General_algorithm_to_compute_ranks_and_bases). If you put your vectors as rows of a matrix and you compute the echelon form you should add the vector $e_i$ if there is no row starting (with $1$) at column $i$.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks <3

Comment: +1 @badatmath, do observe that the same algorithm works with any field (e.g. the reals) in place of $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Cool observation,